# SupportMapFragment and NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to use SupportMapFragment and I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.c.o()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.z.b(Unknown Source)
```

The error appears somewhere here:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    } else {
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    }

    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

I implemented the OnMapReadyCallBack:

```
public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

I don't catch where the null reference is.

The onCreate Function:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
}
```

Stack-Track:

```
03-22 22:38:07.291    3758-3758/itcc.li.lieventuregradle E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: itcc.li.lieventuregradle, PID: 3758
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.c.o()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.z.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:115)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onResume(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onResume(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$7.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onResume(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onResume(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1829)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:993)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

fragment_maps.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Please disable proguard and provide normal stack trace with proper line where do you have NPE. But almost sure that it just not find fragment by id. Please provide your onCreateView method implementation as well as xml file

Comment: In text of question with normal formatting please.

Comment: Sorry, new in this forum. The supportMapFragment ist not null: SupportMapFragment{1399afb5 #0 id=0x7f0b0063}

Comment: fragment_maps.xml please.

Comment: Code is also here: https://github.com/thomasE1993/Lieventure.git on branch "gradle"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem 1)**

If the following line is really in your code (which is correct)

```
public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment ...
```

then remove the `onCreateView` method.

You're trying to inflate a map fragment into a map fragment.

**Problem 2)**

Get rid of this abomination.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
} else {
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
}
```

You access the fragment manager from a fragment by calling `getFragmentManager()` or `getChildFragmentManager()` depending on which you need. Both will be instances of a support fragment manager since you're working in a support fragment.

Also you don't have to find a map fragment, you're it.

**Problem 3)**

Respect lifecycle logic. Call `super.onViewCreated(...)` at the beginning of overridden the method and `super.onDestroyView()` at the end of the overridden method (if you will use it). In the same way you want the fragment's ancestors initialize first and clean up last.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of service

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec: You are right. If we extend SupportMapFragment, no need to call onCreateView(). Now, how do i play with it? Like zoom in, zoom out etc.

Comment: @akshayrajkore Get a `GoogleMap` instance via `void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`. Then https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap